# It is a decision resulting from "animal spirits", singular or plural?

Tags: plural-forms

I wrote the sentence

"It is a decision resulting from 'animal spirits'" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_spirits_(Keynes)),

but now I feel unsure about if plural is fine.

Comment: Please explain why you say that, or why you think it may be wrong.

Comment: Are the animal spirits themselves the reason for the decision being made, or is it something about them? E.g. their presence, their influence, their advice etc.

Comment: @DamienH: Animal spirits are the reason for the decision made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the plural is fine.

(Did you know that StackExchange has a minimum character length for answers?  Yes, it does.)

Comment: Is that also the work of the animal spirits, you think? :P